# If $\succsim$ is transitive but irreflexive, then it is asymmetric, proof

Tags: preferences, self-study

### If $\succsim$ is transitive but irreflexive, then it is asymmetric.

this is my proof:

Suppose $\succsim$ is not asymmetric, which means that for any $x,y \in X$ $x\succsim y \rightarrow y \succsim x$. By definition $\succsim$ is transitive, i.e. for any $x, y, z \in X$ we have $x \succsim y$ & $y\succsim z$ $\rightarrow$ $x \succsim z$. So since we are supposing $\succsim$ is symmetric:  $y\succsim x \rightarrow x \succsim$ y. Now since  $\succsim$  is transitive  $y \succsim x$ &  $x\succsim y \rightarrow y \succsim y$ but  $\succsim$  is irreflexive so it's a contradition and  $\succsim$ is asymmetric.

What do you think of my proof, is it wrong or not clear enough?

Comment: Your proof looks good to me.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

A relation that is not asymmetric need not be symmetric. But if $\succsim$ is not asymmetric, there must be elements $y$ and $x$ such that both $x\succsim y$ and $y\succsim x$ hold and these elements are all you need to arrive at a contradiction.

Also, $x\succsim y\implies y\succsim x$ can hold for an asymmetric relation, namely when $x\succsim y$ does not hold.

I'd like also to point out that "any" is ambiguous here and might be read as "all" instead
of the intended "some."

Comment: Ok I undestand that I need to improve the form, but is saying "for any" wrong? I intended it as ∀, why should I say "some"? I just want to be as precise as possible.

Comment: I don't think it is wrong, but "some" is clearer in this context.